# Whitelist not working on PhoneGap 3.0 ios

Tags: ios, cordova, whitelist

I am awar this 1 line of code below is suppose to white domains

```
<access origin="yahoo.com" subdomains="true" />
```

but its not working at all.. every domain is being allowed and i do not know why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you also have one that looks like this `<access origin="*" />`?

Comment: no i don't because adding that will allow all domain access

Comment: this is what i have done.. I have use this code `phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git` to install InAppBrowser and the whitelist doesn't work at all but without the InAppBrowser plugin installed, it opens a webview in fullscreen without a close, done button or any means to get out or the webview but the whitelist works well. Now is it a bug with inappbrowser or the phonegap itself as i read that inappbrowser has already been packages as a part of phonegap 3.0.0

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 config.xml

1. /YourAppName/config.xml     <-- check if you add the access here
2. /YourAppName/ww/config.xml

I had the same problem with you (using phongap 3.0), and it is solved by adding access in the 1st file.